# MySQL returns weird results to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP application and I am trying to retrieve all the data from a table called articles to present them on screen. I have inserted the 2 sample entries, as below:

> ```
> SQL result
>
> Host: localhost
> Database: samples
> Generation Time: Oct 28, 2013 at 09:04 PM
> Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.0.8 / MySQL 5.5.30-log
> SQL query: SELECT * FROM `articles` LIMIT 0, 30 ;
> Rows: 2
>
> article_id    article_title   article_content article_timestamp   
> 3 Sample title    Text    0
> 4 Title   Content 1234567
> ```

Here is the code that causes the error, with a small debugging print in there:

```
<?php
class Article {
    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;
        $query = "Select * from articles";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $res_array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        foreach ($res_array as $x) {
            echo $x;
            echo "............";
        }
    }
}?>
```

Instead of getting 2 entries, I get only the first 1...in double. To be more precise:

> 3............3............Sample title............Sample title............Text............Text............0............0............

I am not sure, what I am doing wrong in here. Can someone give a hint?

Comment: What is that `$pdo` if you're using `mysql_*`?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` fetches _one_ row from the result, with _both_ numerical _as_ associative indexes.

Comment: Use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*` . `mysql_` statements are going to be removed in the future.

Comment: @MahanGM, dont get confused by the name...I impemented it in the beginning with PDO but I tried mysql_* due to some setup issues. I just left the name as is, to avoid broken references in multiple files. It is a todo task as soon as I will settle in the method

Comment: @estXcrew, thanks, I will migrate

Comment: @Wrikken, really? Damn....I thought I was pretty sure it returned all the rows. Thansk for mentioning

Comment: @py_script I'm not confused. I felt you are going to fool us that you're using PDO.

Comment: Lol, no...why should I do that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you call `mysql_fetch_array` only once, that's why you're getting only one row. You should call it in a loop until it returns fale value, meaning no more rows in a resultset.

Second, by default, `mysql_fetch_array` returns a bizzare hybrid of hash and array, an array indexed both by column numbers and column names, which explains why values are duplicated. You can pass `MYSQL_NUM` to get only values indexed by column numbers.

```
while ($res_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    foreach ($res_array as $x) {
        echo $x;
        echo "............";
    }
    echo "\n"; // ???
}
```

Comment: Yeah, figured it previously :)
So, given the chance is that the reason I get even more weird results, if I do echo $res_array?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've used in the past:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  foreach ($row as $x) {
    // ...
  }
}
?>
```

This retrieves each row in turn and loops through it to output the results.

Using `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns only an associative array, reducing the duplicate values in the array.

Comment: Combine this answer with using `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` or `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` or `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)` to eliminate the duplicate columns

Comment: @MarkBaker I prefer to use mysql_fetch_assoc() myself, but the OP was using mysql_fetch_array. You make a good point, though. I edited to make that clear.

Comment: Good, I dont want duplicates in my case

Answer (score 0):

PHP Manual:

`mysql_fetch_array(resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ])`

**Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).**

So you should write this: `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

Comment: That would eliminate the duplicates, but not return his second record. So really only a partial answer.